# Need to show results on the frontend of an admin form

Tags: forms

I hope someone can help me as I'm fairly new to this.

I created a very simple plugin for my own site, but I've had a few people ask me for it because they like the functionality of it. However, they want to customise the main headings (h2 and h3). I added an options form to the admin area, but I don't know how to get the results to show on the front end. Any help would be greatly appreciated and fantastic.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Related Products Out of Stock Display 
Plugin URI: http://example.com/
Description: Displays related products above gallery when items are out of 
stock. Relies on categories and tags for best results 
Author: John Cook 
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.example.com
License: GPL2
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
'my_related_out_of_stock', 15);
function my_related_out_of_stock () {
global $product;
$availability = $product->get_availability();

/*check if availability in the array = string 'Out of Stock'
**if so display on page.
*/
if ( $availability['availability'] == 'Out of stock') {
echo '<h2>';
echo WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0;
echo '</h2>';
echo '<h3>';
echo WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1;
echo '</h3>';
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => 4,  
'columns' => 4,  
'orderby' => 'rand' 
); 
woocommerce_related_products( apply_filters( 'my_related_out_of_stock_args', $args ) ); 
}
}
/*
**
**
**options page
**
**
*/
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'WOOS_Related_Products_add_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'WOOS_Related_Products_settings_init' );


function WOOS_Related_Products_add_admin_menu() { 

add_options_page( 'Wordpress out of stock related products', 'Wordpress out of stock related products', 'manage_options', 'wordpress_out_of_stock_related_products', 'WOOS_Related_Products_options_page' );

}


function WOOS_Related_Products_settings_init() { 

register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'WOOS_Related_Products_settings' );

add_settings_section(
    'WOOS_Related_Products_pluginPage_section', 
    __( 'Create your custom out of stock message to display before related products', 'wordpress' ), 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_settings_section_callback', 
    'pluginPage'
);

add_settings_field( 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0', 
    __( 'Main heading', 'wordpress' ), 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0_render', 
    'pluginPage', 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_pluginPage_section' 
);

add_settings_field( 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1', 
    __( 'Sub heading', 'wordpress' ), 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1_render', 
    'pluginPage', 
    'WOOS_Related_Products_pluginPage_section' 
);


}


function WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'WOOS_Related_Products_settings' );
?>
<input type='text' name='WOOS_Related_Products_settings[WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0]' value='<?php echo $options['WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0']; ?>'>
<?php

}


function WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'WOOS_Related_Products_settings' );
?>
<input type='text' name='WOOS_Related_Products_settings[WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1]' value='<?php echo $options['WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1']; ?>'>
<?php

}


function WOOS_Related_Products_settings_section_callback(  ) { 

echo __( 'Create a custom message for your shoppers when they encounter an item that is out of stock. This custom message will appear before the related products', 'wordpress' );

}


function WOOS_Related_Products_options_page(  ) { 

?>
<form action='options.php' method='post'>

    <h1>Wordpress out of stock related products</h1>

    <?php
    settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
    do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
    submit_button();
    ?>

</form>
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: you can read the values in the same way that in backend with `$options = get_option( 'WOOS_Related_Products_settings' );`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I follow what you mean. You might have to ELI5 to me.
What I'm trying to show is the results from the form in the h2 and h3 on the frontend. I feel like I'm close, but yet so far

Comment: yes it's that, look what is in `$options`.

Comment: where you save WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_0 and WOOS_Related_Products_text_field_1?

Comment: Hi Manyang. Yes, I want to display the entered text from the form fields in the admin area in those fields on the frontend where the h2 and h3 are